# Not able to use BigQuery operator in Apache Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am creating a Data pipeline where I fetch data from BigQuery either through Bigquery operator or google cloud library. But I am always getting an error. Following is the dag for big query operator:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_check_operator import BigQueryCheckOperator

from read_val_send1 import read,validating_hit,track_google_analytics_event,add_gcp_connection

default_args = {
    "owner" : "Airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date" : datetime(2021,5,9),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds = 5)
}

dag = DAG("Automp", default_args = default_args, schedule_interval = "@daily", catchup = False)

activateGCP = PythonOperator(
        task_id='add_gcp_connection_python',
        python_callable=add_gcp_connection,
        provide_context=True, dag = dag
    )
BQ_CONN_ID = "my_gcp_conn"
BQ_PROJECT = 'pii-test'
BQ_DATASET = 'some_Dataset'

t1 = BigQueryCheckOperator(
        task_id='bq_check',
        sql='''
        #standardSQL
        Select * from table''',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        bigquery_conn_id=BQ_CONN_ID,
        dag=dag
    )
activateGCP >> t1
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKp0t.png)

I have attached the error image

Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/Automp.py] No module named 'httplib2'

I am not able to install python packages in airflow as well with required.txt file. Following is compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    redis:
        image: 'redis:5.0.5'
        # command: redis-server --requirepass redispass

    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        # Uncomment these lines to persist data on the local filesystem.
        #     - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        # volumes:
        #     - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

    flower:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        ports:
            - "5555:5555"
        command: flower

    scheduler:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        command: scheduler

    worker:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - scheduler
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        environment:
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        command: worker
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOvp5.png)

Comment: Have you tried by installing the missing package? https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/ should be sufficient

Comment: Hi @dhruv I am facing one issue with creating google bigquery connection from Airflow UI. Without the connection I will not have BQ_CONN_ID which I suppose to use in BigqueryOperator. Do you know hot fix it or can we create a connection in python code itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image that you are using does not include the `httplib2` package, which is perhaps used by the imports coming from the `read_val_send1` directory.

What you can do is adding the following line on your `./requirements.txt`.

```
httplib2==0.19.1
```

The [puckel's docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) setup has an [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh#L28) that supports `pip install -r requirements.txt`. So this must be sufficient.

In case something goes wrong you can always use [Docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) or [Docker interactive execute bash](http://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2017/03/13/docker-usage.html) to see what is going wrong.

I also recommend using [the latest docker-compose for Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml) to have a smoother workflow.